# fetch branches in a github wiki

Tags: git, github, branch, wiki

Since GitHub wikis are git repositories unto themselves, it should follow that one could create branches.  Even GH suggests [in there documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/#cloning-wikis-locally-to-your-computer) that this is possible.

I've done this with my wiki and pushed it up to GH.  But when I pull the repo, it only pulls the master branch, and I can't see any others.

Is there a way that I can access the other branches?

**Edit 1**

- I know that the wiki is a separate repo. That's what I'm trying to pull.
- I tried cloning it to a different folder, and only the master branch is fetched.

Comment: `git checkout <repo> && git fetch && git checkout <branch>`?

Comment: @Cyclonecode do you mean git clone? Surely if you clone you don’t need to fetch?

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but I can't remember the name of my branch, and `git branch` only lists master.

Comment: @gregsdennis Where did you get wiki repo with multiple branches?

Comment: Their docs say you can. Only master *will be shown online*. See the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki of your repository is stored as a **different** repository.
GitHub displays it under your project.

#### How to clone a Wiki GitHub repo?

```
# Clones the wiki locally
git clone https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.wiki.git

# or using ssh
git clone git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.wiki.git
```

#### List all branches

You can use `git branch -a` which will display all your branches both local and remotes and now you will be able to checkout any existing branch.

```
# list all local and remote branches
git branch -a

# checkout any required branch
git checkout <branch name>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it's a different repo. My problem is that I'm only able to get the master branch. No others will appear.

Comment: try: `git fetch --all`

Comment: @gregsdennis What does git branch -v tell you

Comment: do you have any other branches in your wiki: `git branch -a` to display all bracnhes

Comment: using the `-v` branch only shows master, but the -a branch shows all of them.  From there I can checkout specific branches by name!  That did it.  Please update your answer, and I'll mark it.